# Refresh the page after clicking on the area

Tags: html, css

I want to refresh my website after clicking on a specific area (container)

Any ideas?

THANKS!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend checking out [mcve]

Comment: Use an html button that redirect to the page url you are already on I got this from another stack overflow answer: <button value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload();">

Comment: You can use an a href to '#' as the src or you can use javascript to `window.location.reload()` when something is clicked.

Comment: `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Try to add more information to your question as well including code that you have tried and any research you have done

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Location.reload()` API interface (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

So the answer could look as follows:

```
document.querySelector('you-area-selector-here').addEventListener((click) => {
   window.location.reload(true);
})
```

`true` flag is required to be sure the page was reloaded from server, not from cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to mix js with HTML.

I would do it this way:

```
let refreshPage = document.querySelector('#div1').addEventListener('click', => {
   location.reload();
   })
```

note: you must give id or class to the element you are trying to select in this function.
There are other way of doing it i.e = document.querySelectorAll, getElementById, getElementByClassName, getElementByTagName.